# Backbone collection.get() doesn't restore a model with is methods

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, model

I am working on an online/offline application and I have noticed this :

I fetch in my collection my offline retrieve from localStorage. (everytime a user log in online, I save him with addition datas retrieved from my server)

If the same user now try to log in offline, I check if this operator match any operators in my collection and if It match an entry, I return the operator match.

The problem is, the operator that I get from collection.get(#id) doesn't have any methods from the backbone operator model.

Before correcting my code was looking like this :

```
if( this.isLocalValidOperator( operator ) ){
  var operatorMatch = this.get(operator.get('id'));
  cb( operatorMatch );
}
```

My correction, now it work

```
if( this.isLocalValidOperator( operator ) ){
  var operatorMatch = this.get(operator.get('id'));
  // must add additional attributes from the match, then return the operator created with new Operator( someAttributes )
  operator.set({ 
    isSuperadmin: operatorMatch.get('isSuperadmin'),
    isModerator: operatorMatch.get('isModerator'),
    firstname: operatorMatch.get('firstname'),
    lastname: operatorMatch.get('lastname')
  });
  cb( operator );
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are `operator` and `operatorMatch` different objects? Why do you expect them to have the same attributes?

Comment: They are the same object. because operatorMatch is an entry of operatorCollection which is a operator collection ^^,

Comment: No, `b = collection.get(a.get('id'))` only means that `b.id === a.id`. Perhaps a function demo on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com would help clarify things.

Comment: [// @Backbone doc // getcollection.get(id) : Get a model from a collection, specified by an id, a cid, or by passing in a model.]

We need a jsfiddle example since this is pretty clear, getting a model from a collection will not restore model's methode. I'm wondering why and how to hack this.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes across this or similar issue of losing methods... I was losing methods when restoring from localStorage but the property data was still there. The problem was that in the collection I was missing the property:

`model: ModelName`

After I included that, methods remained intact on page reload.